# How to provide relative path to folder icons in external hard disk

Tags: windows-7, icons

I am trying to set the folder icon in my external hard disk folders. In my PC the hard disk letter is `'J'` and I have the icons inside the target folder, Icon for `SampleFolder` is within SampleFolder and when I select that icon the path is `J:\SampleFolder\Sample.ico`. When the hard disk is plugged to other computer the disk letter is different and the customized icons are not appearing. I tried using `.\SampleFolder\Sample.ico` resulted in error. Is there is any way to provide relative path for icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a file called desktop.ini inside each folder and fill it with this content:

```
 [.ShellClassInfo]
 IconResource=..\Icons\my_resourceDLL.dll,XXX
```

Or:

```
IconResource=..\Icons\icon.ico,0

Where XXX is the icon number. ..\Icons is a relative path, you can use your own dir name.
```